# Python: finding lowest integer

Tags: python, list, integer

I have the following code:

```
l = ['-1.2', '0.0', '1']

x = 100.0
for i in l:
    if i < x:
        x = i
print x
```

The code should find the lowest value in my list (-1.2) but instead when i print 'x' it finds the value is still 100.0
Where is my code going wrong?

Comment: It looks like you want "list = [1.2, 0.0, 1]" instead of quoted values. (Also lower case L is a bad variable name... it looks too much like a one).

Comment: An integer is a whole number like 4, 20, 0, and -2. Numbers like -1.2 are not integers. Do you understand that? How does this relate to what you want to do here?

Comment: What you have up there are `str` values, not `int` values; you can't evaluate `str` value, because they are not `int`s.

Answer (score 42):

To find the minimum value of a list, you might just as well use [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min):

```
x = min(float(s) for s in l) # min of a generator
```

Or, if you want the result as a string, rather than a float, use a [key function](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions):

```
x = min(l, key=float)
```

Comment: `min` has a `key` argument for cases similar to this, with usage like `x = min(l, key=float)`. It is slightly different than the code posted in that it returns an item from the original iterable (i.e., the string `'-1.2'`) rather than the resultant thing (i.e. the float `-1.2`).

Comment: @OlivierVerdier Is there a particular reason that you do the `float(s) for s in l` part? Why can't you just do `min(l)`? I just tried that out and it works. What would be the difference?

Answer (score 24):

You aren't comparing integers, you're comparing strings. Strings compare lexicographically -- meaning character by character -- instead of (as you seem to want) by converting the value to a float. Make your list hold numbers (floats or integers, depending on what you want), or convert the strings to floats or integers in your loop, before you compare them.

You may also be interested in the `min` builtin function, which already does what your current loop does (without the converting, that is.)

Answer (score 18):

It looks like you want to convert the list to a list of numbers

```
>>> foo = ['-1.2', '0.0', '1']
>>> bar = map(float, foo)
>>> bar
[-1.2, 0.0, 1.0]
>>> min(bar)
-1.2
```

or if it really is strings you want, that you want to use `min`'s `key` argument

```
>>> foo = ['-1.2', '0.0', '1']
>>> min(foo, key=float)
'-1.2'
```

Answer (score 6):

Python has a built in `min` function to help you with finding the smallest.

However, you need to convert your list items to numbers before you can find the lowest integer( what, isn't that float? )

```
min(float(i) for i in l)
```

Answer (score 3):

`l` is a list of strings. When you put numbers between single quotes like that, you are creating strings, which are just a sequence of characters. To make your code work properly, you would have to do this:

```
l = [-1.2, 0.0, 1]  # no quotation marks

x = 100.0
for i in l:
    if i < x:
        x = i
print x
```

If you must use a list of strings, you can try to let Python try to make a number out of each string. This is similar to [Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622994/python-finding-lowest-integer/2623004#2623004), except it understands floating-point (decimal) numbers correctly.

```
l = ['-1.2', '0.0', '1']

x = 100.0
for i in l:
    inum = float(i)
    if inum < x:
        x = inum
print x
```

---

I hope that this is code that you are writing to learn either Python or programming in general. If this is the case, great. However, if this is production code, consider using Python's built-in functions.

```
l = ['-1.2', '0.0', '1']
lnums = map(float, l)  # turn strings to numbers
x = min(lnums)  # find minimum value
print x
```

Answer (score 3):

```
number_list = [99.5,1.2,-0.3]

number_list.sort()

print number_list[0]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to complete the answer. With no explanation and just code, this answer is not helpful as a solution (not to mention if it even solves the problem).

Answer (score 2):

Cast the variable to a float before doing the comparison:

```
if float(i) < float(x):
```

The problem is that you are comparing strings to floats, which will not work.

Comment: Thanks, serves me right for trying to answer a question early on a Monday :)

Answer (score 2):

```
list1 = [10,-4,5,2,33,4,7,8,2,3,5,8,99,-34]

print(list1)

max_v=list1[0]

min_v=list1[0]

for x in list1:
    if x>max_v:
        max_v=x
        print('X is {0} and max is {1}'.format(x,max_v))
for x in list1:
    if x<min_v:
        min_v=x
        print('X is {0} and min is {1}'.format(x,min_v))

print('Max values is ' + str(max_v))
print('Min values is ' + str(min_v))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or no float conversion at all by just specifying floats in the list.

```
l = [-1.2, 0.0, 1]
x = min(l)
```

or

```
l = min([-1.2, 0.0, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [-1.2, 0.0, 1]

x = 100.0
for i in l:
    if i < x:
        x = i
print (x)
```

This is the answer, i needed this for my homework, took your code, and i deleted the " " around the numbers, it then worked, i hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

You have to start somewhere the correct code should be:

**The code to return the minimum value**

`l = [ '0.0', '1','-1.2']
x = l[0]
for i in l:
    if i < x:
        x = i
print x`

But again it's good to use directly integers instead of using quotations `''`

**This way**!

`l = [ 0.0, 1,-1.2]
x = l[0]
for i in l:
    if i < x:
        x = i
print x`

Answer (score 0):

You have strings in the list and you are comparing them with the number 100.0.

Answer (score -1):

'''Functions'''

```
import math

#functions
def min3(x1,x2,x3):
    if x1<= x2 and x1<= x3:
        return x1
    elif x2<= x1 and x2<= x3:
        return x2
    elif x3<= x2 and x3<= x1:
          return x3
print(min3(4, 7, 5))

print(min3(4, 5, 5))

print(min3(4, 4, 4))

print(min3(-2, -6, -100))

print(min3("Z", "B", "A"))
```