# Find the smallest number in a python list and print the position

Tags: python, list

I have a list of integer imported via a file

```
xy = [50, 2, 34, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2]
```

I am aware of [Python: finding lowest integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622994/python-finding-lowest-integer)

However, I wonder how can I print the position of it instead of just finding the smallest number?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just use the `list.index` method:

```
print xy.index(min(xy))
# 6
```

If the minimum is repeated, you'll only get the index of the first occurrence, though.

Comment: Epic solution! You are demonstrating a clear case for the superiority of the pythonic way :) +1 seems almost mean.

Answer (score 3):

```
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(xy) if x == min(xy)]    # Indices of all min occurrences
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone wishes to use for loop:

```
xy = [50, 2, 34, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2] 
t=0
for i in range(len(xy)):
    if xy[i]<xy[t]:
        t=i
print t
```